# AWS DocumentDB does not use indexes when $sort and $match at the same time

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

DocumentDB ignores indexes of any field instead of sorted

```
db.requests.aggregate([
    { $match: {'DeviceId': '5f68c9c1-73c1-e5cb-7a0b-90be2f80a332'}},
    { $sort: { 'Timestamp': 1 } }
])
```

Useful information:

```
> explain('executionStats')
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "admin_portal.requests",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "indexName" : "Timestamp_1",
            "direction" : "forward"
        }
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "executionTimeMillis" : "398883.755",
        "planningTimeMillis" : "0.274",
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : "20438",
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : "398879.028",
            "indexName" : "Timestamp_1",
            "direction" : "forward"
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
       ...
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1622585939, 1)
}
```

```
> db.requests.getIndexKeys()
[
    {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    {
        "Timestamp" : 1
    },
    {
        "DeviceId" : 1
    }
]
```

It works fine when I query documents without sorting or when I use **find** and **sort** function instead of aggregation.

**Important note:** *Also it works perfect on original MongoDB instance, but not on the DocumentDB*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of "how does DocumentDB choose a query plan" kind of question.
There are many answers on how Mongo [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429105/10770370) it on stackoverflow.

Clearly choosing the "wrong" index can happen from failed trials based on data distribution, the issue here is that DocumentDB adds an [unknown layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html).

> Amazon DocumentDB emulates the MongoDB 4.0 API on a purpose-built database engine that utilizes a distributed, fault-tolerant, self-healing storage system. As a result, query plans and the output of explain() ***may differ*** between Amazon DocumentDB and MongoDB. Customers who want control over their query plan can use the $hint operator to enforce selection of a preferred index.

They state that due to this layer differences might happen.

So now that we understand why a wrong index is selected ( kind of ). what can we do? well unless you want to drop or rebuilt your indexes differently somehow then you need to use the [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#syntax) options for your pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, {hint: "index_name"})
```